# Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 "The network connection was lost in swift5

Tags: alamofire, swift5

I am using swift5 & Xcode Version 13.0 (13A233). I am using cocapod

```
 pod 'Alamofire' , '~> 4.9.1'
```

I just connect using IP, it is working fine.But when I connect to domain like  https://www.example.net it shows

```
     Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 "The network connection was lost." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-4, NSUnderlyingError=0x600002af2b50 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1005 "(null)" UserInfo={NSErrorPeerAddressKey=<CFData 0x6000007c8230 [0x1056ddaf0]>{length = 16, capacity = 16, bytes = 0x100201bb772858170000000000000000}, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-4, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4}}, _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <A49E8D5B-1DE3-487C-B4F7-50376AF188AE>.<3>, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
        "LocalDataTask <A49E8D5B-1DE3-487C-B4F7-50376AF188AE>.<3>"
    ), NSLocalizedDescription=The network connection was lost., NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://www.example.net/api/second-api, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://www.example.net/api/second-api, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4}
```

I have also add App Transport Security Settings like bellow & here is the image
[image]

Here is the code I have used..

1. API One:

   ```
       func firstApi() {

           Alamofire.request("https://www.example.net/api/first-api", method: .post, parameters: [
               "param1":"",
               "param2":"",
           ],headers: headers).responseJSON{ [self](responseData) -> Void in
               secondApi()
           }

       }
   ```
2. API Two:

   ```
         func secondApi() {

           Alamofire.request("https://www.example.net/api/second-api", method: .post, parameters: [
               "param1":"",
               "param2":"",
               "param3":"",
           ],headers: headers).responseJSON{ [self](responseData) -> Void in

           }

       }
   ```

In the above code, I have called Second API from first API. First API is responding nicely. But in second API which I call from first API response  shows above error..

**But Only single API called but when I call another API from single API shows error**

I don't know what is reason. Please help me to solve the problem..

Comment: I suggest upgrading to Alamofire 5 (there's no reason to use 4 in new code) and then debugging your connection to the failing domain. Can other tools connect? Can the browser?

Comment: @JonShier I have used android & I also tested from locally which is based on IP like http://ip/ . it is working fine but when I call from domin it shows error